# How SQL Server iterates over rows when computing several aggregate functions in one select query

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012

And query

```
SELECT ManagerId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SoldInDay < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as badSoldDays,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DaysWithSoldPc

FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY ProductId
```

Some Table Definition

```
ManagerId | SoldInDay | Category

    1         50          PC
    1         20          Laptop
    2         30          PC
    3         40          Laptop
```

So, question is:
Does it mean that Sql will iterate over all rows twice? so, each aggregate function executes in separate cycle over all rows in table? or it's much smarter?

Doesn't matter what I want to get by this query, it's my dream.

Comment: Short answer is no: it's not going to iterate over the rows again for each additional sum. (don't know enough about the internals to post a full answer)

Comment: Why not run the query and a variation with only one of the aggregate columns and have a little look at their execution plans?

Comment: @gvee Thank's! That's it, after several tries and studies execution plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It appears that your question was addressed by a comment, but for completeness, I've provided an official answer here.)

First, your example SQL will not run. You are including ManagerId in the field list but not the GROUP BY. You will get an error akin to this:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Column '@SomeTable.ManagerID' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Assuming you meant "ManagerId" instead of "ProductId" in the field list, I reproduced your situation and reviewed the execution plans. It showed only one "Stream Aggregate" operator. You can force it to run over the table twice by separating the aggregations into two different common table expressions (CTEs) and JOINing them back together. In that case, you see two Stream Aggregate operators (one for each run through the table).

[image: Query Plan Showing Treatment of Multiple Aggregates]

Here is the code to generate the execution plans:

```
DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE
(
    ManagerId int,
    SoldInDay int,
    Category varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @SomeTable (ManagerId, SoldInDay, Category) VALUES (1, 50, 'PC');
INSERT INTO @SomeTable (ManagerId, SoldInDay, Category) VALUES (1, 20, 'Laptop');
INSERT INTO @SomeTable (ManagerId, SoldInDay, Category) VALUES (2, 30, 'PC');
INSERT INTO @SomeTable (ManagerId, SoldInDay, Category) VALUES (3, 40, 'Laptop');

/*

This produces an error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column '@SomeTable.ManagerID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SELECT
    ManagerId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SoldInDay < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as badSoldDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DaysWithSoldPc
FROM        @SomeTable
GROUP BY    ProductId;

*/

SELECT
    ManagerId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SoldInDay < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BadSoldDays,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DaysWithSoldPc
FROM        @SomeTable
GROUP BY    ManagerId;

WITH DaysWithSoldPcTable AS
(
    SELECT
        ManagerId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DaysWithSoldPc
    FROM        @SomeTable
    GROUP BY    ManagerId
), BadSoldDaysTable AS
(
    SELECT
        ManagerId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN SoldInDay < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BadSoldDays
    FROM        @SomeTable
    GROUP BY    ManagerId
)
SELECT
    DaysWithSoldPcTable.ManagerId,
    DaysWithSoldPcTable.DaysWithSoldPc,
    BadSoldDaysTable.BadSoldDays
FROM        DaysWithSoldPcTable
JOIN        BadSoldDaysTable
ON          DaysWithSoldPcTable.ManagerId = BadSoldDaysTable.ManagerId;
```